# Find the length (in cm.) of the hypotenuse?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, inequality

> A right angled triangle has sides of length X, Y and Z (all lengths in cm.).
>   It is known that Z is the length of the longest side.
>
> The lengths of the other two sides satisfy the inequality 
>   $$\sqrt{x^2-4\sqrt{2}x + 12} + \sqrt{y^2-6\sqrt{3}y + 31}  \leq 4$$
>
> What is the length (in cm.) of the hypotenuse of this triangle?

How can we get the exact value of $x$ and $y$?
Since during solving equation get in the power of 8 and very complicated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $x^2-4\sqrt{2}+12 = (x-2\sqrt{2})^2 + 4$ and $y^2-6\sqrt{3}y+31 = (y-3\sqrt{3})^2 + 4$. That means that each square root is *at least* equal to $2$, and strictly larger than $2$ if the first square is nonzero.

Answer (score 3):

we start by rewriting the first radicand
\begin{align*}
  x^2 - 4\sqrt 2 x + 12 &= (x - 2\sqrt 2)^2 - (2\sqrt 2)^2 + 12\\
                        &= (x - 2\sqrt 2)^2 + 4
\end{align*}
for the second one we get
\begin{align*}
  y^2 - 6\sqrt 3y  + 31 &= (y - 3\sqrt 3)^2 - (3\sqrt 3)^2 + 31\\
                        &= (y - 3\sqrt 3)^2 + 4
\end{align*}Now, as squares are positive, we obtain 
$$
  \sqrt{x^2 - 4\sqrt 2 x + 12} = \sqrt{(x - 2\sqrt 2)^2 + 4} \ge \sqrt 4 = 2 
$$
and similarly $\sqrt{y^2 - 6\sqrt 3y  + 31} \ge 2$. Now since each term is at least 2, there sum is only less than 4 if they are both exactly equal 2. This happens if $x - 2\sqrt 2 = y - 3\sqrt 3 = 0$.

So we have $x = 2\sqrt 2$, $y = 3\sqrt 3$ and $z  = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = \sqrt{8 + 27} = \sqrt{35}$.

AB,